# how to get a particular value from table and store in variable in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

iam trying to store value from database into a variable inside procedure and increment its value by 1. This is what i do:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`satish`@`%` PROCEDURE `p_authTeacher`(
IN username VARCHAR(35),
IN pwd VARCHAR(35),
OUT msg INT,  
OUT msg1 INT,
OUT msg2 INT
)
BEGIN
select (COUNT(*) > 0) INTO @result from login where User_Name = username and    User_Password = md5(pwd);

SET msg = @result;  
IF @result = 1 THEN
select (COUNT(*)>0) into @result1 from login where User_Name = username and User_Password = md5(pwd) and Is_New ='F';
if @result1= 1 Then
UPDATE login SET Last_login=now() where User_Name = username and User_Password = md5(pwd);
SET msg1 = @result1;
END IF;
if @result1= 0 Then
UPDATE login SET Last_login=now() where User_Name = username and User_Password = md5(pwd);
SET msg1 = @result1;    
END IF;
END IF; 
IF @result = 0 THEN
    select Password_Attempts into @attempts from login where User_Name = username ;
    SET msg2 = @attempts;
update login set Password_Attempts=1 where username = uname;
END IF;
END
```

trying to store value of column(Password_Attempts) where username = uname of login table.
add 1 into it and update into database. But certainly i got Syntax error. Please help me on this. the last if block is not working even if the Username  and password doesn't match.

Comment: At what line do you get syntax error? And why not use `update login set Password_Attempts=Password_Attempts+1 where username = uname;` at the last line?

Comment: its gives me error in line 1 at where(error: unexpected where).

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) link for a correct syntax of `SELECT ... INTO`. You should put `INTO` before `FROM`:

```
select Password_Attempts into @attempts from login where User_Name = uname ;
```

Comment: thank you David it removes error though i wont get what i want. im going to edit my procedure with its fuller version please look into it.

Comment: You should also rephrase question, specifying, what you get along with the sample data.